# Clearing Textarea on Blur (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, background, textarea, swap, blur

```
// Clearing Textarea
$('textarea').focus(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.data(this, 'img', $this.css('background-image'));
   $this.css('background-image', 'none');
});
$('textarea').blur(function() {
    if($.trim($('textarea').val()).length){
         $this.css('background-image', 'none');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-image', $.data(this, 'img'));
    }
});
```

When I click out of the textarea, and although there is content present in it, I still see the background image.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would've easily found this error if you were using the Firebug extension for Firefox :) I highly recommend it for Javascripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085605/clearing-textarea-on-blur-jquery/3085623#3085623) said. `$this` wasn't defined. What you needed to do was `$(this)`:

```
$('textarea').blur(function() {
  if($.trim($('textarea').val()).length){
    // Added () around $this
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-image', $.data(this, 'img'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your blur function, you have $this, but it is never defined.  You only defined it in the scope of the focus() function.